# Why is my website's mobile version not working properly?

Tags: responsive-design, dreamweaver

I have created a webpage using Dreamweaver and the mobile view is not showing properly on my website after uploading using Cpanel. This webpage is a practice site that my boss asked me to work on.

I have set the mobile view to trigger from 0 to 720px width. When I do live preview on my smartphone using the live preview of Dreamweaver all looks ok but when I upload the files on Cpanel and visit the actual site from my phone the mobile view does not trigger at all.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QreAZ.png)

Here is how it looks in the actual website: http://www.simplifiednaturals.com/VivaslimSNC1/

Please help. I am very new to website development and only know basic stuff.

Comment: And it seems `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">` is missing in the `head`.

Comment: Hey Johannes, sorry about that. I mean 720px wide. Thanks. I'll add the line that you suggested and see if it works! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Update: @Johannes code worked! <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"> Thanks!